# Issue related to return value in batch file

Tags: batch-file, return

In batch file, I launch multiple executable files using the START command. All run simultaneously very well.

My problem is I want my batch script to receive the returned error code of each executable file. How can I do this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But still problem is not solve.
I have to start run multiple .exe simultaneously in batch file.  Each program require 2 min time for execution. i want each .exe ruturn value after 2 min for all

Comment: Your comment is misplaced. It belongs below the answer(s) to which you are referring.

Answer (score 1):

START your commands via CMD /C so that you can write the returned ERRORLEVEL to a temporary file. Then wait for all return files to be created, read the values, and delete the temp files.

The CMD /V:ON option enables delayed expansion so that it is convenient to access the returned error code from the command line. The delayed expansion also prevents `!errorlevel!>cmd1.return`, when ERRORLEVEL=1, from being interpreted as redirection of stdout.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:: Make sure no temp return files exist yet
del *.return 2>nul

:: Launch your commands, and write return value to temp return files
start "" cmd /v:on /c "yourCommand1 & echo !errorlevel!>cmd1.return"
start "" cmd /v:on /c "yourCommand2 & echo !errorlevel!>cmd2.return"
start "" cmd /v:on /c "yourCommand3 & echo !errorlevel!>cmd3.return"

:Wait for commands to finish
for %%N in (1 2 3) do if not exist cmd%%N.return goto :Wait

:: Read return values and delete temp files
for %%N in (1 2 3) do <cmd%%N.return set /p "cmd%%N="
del *.return

:: Display results
echo command 1 return = %cmd1%
echo command 2 return = %cmd2%
echo command 3 return = %cmd3%
```

Answer (score 0):

Run 'if /?' and you will see more details.
Generally you do `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 command...`.
BTW - if you use `CALL` to run the executalbe then activation is serial and you can view each executable return code when it exits.

Comment: But the OP wants the executable processes to run asynchronously, in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

```
start /wait prog
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: But the OP wants the executable processes to run asynchronously, in parallel.